# Unable to run nvidia-docker. docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:

Tags: linux, docker, nvidia-docker

I was trying to re-implement this [code](https://github.com/msracver/Deep-Exemplar-based-Colorization/tree/linux-docker-colorization-net) from Github and it requires me to install nvidia-docker and run it. The installation of nvidia-docker seemed successful. However, when I run the command `nvidia-docker run -it --ipc=host deep-colorization`, it throws the following error::

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"process_linux.go:432: running prestart hook 1 caused \\\"error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: driver error: failed to process request\\\\n\\\"\"": unknown.
```

ERRO[0002] error waiting for container: context canceled

I am not sure what the error means as I don't have any previous experience with the docker ecosystem. Any kind of assistance is appreciated. I am running Ubuntu 18 by the way.

Thanking you in advance.